# Chrome browser instance spawned from Selenium Chromedriver is slower from my framework as compared to a simple Java project

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

We have a web UI test automation framework that uses Selenium WebDriver for web UI automation.

**Type of project**

- Maven based
- CucumberJVM for framework structure and separation of concerns. (Gherkin steps, business layer, page objects)
- We also use Spring DI to manage certain utilities and page objects lifecycle whenever they are used as dependencies in other classes.
- PageFactory for locators.
- Element listeners (via EventFiringWebDriverFactory)

**Critical dependencies that we are using that will be important to know here**

- Selenium client java binding version: 3.141.59
- Webdriver manager: 3.6.1

**Options we set for Chrome Driver instantiation**

```
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
options.addArguments("--disable-quic");
return options;
```

**How we add driver listeners**

```
protected void addDriverListeners() {
    // Add event listeners
    List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    listeners.add(new ElementListener());
    driver = EventFiringWebDriverFactory.getEventFiringWebDriver(driver, listeners);
  }
```

**How we initialise pagefactory elements**

```
protected void initPageFactoryElements() {
    String[] beanDefinitionNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();

    for (int i = 0; i < beanDefinitionNames.length; i++) {
      Object page = applicationContext.getBean(beanDefinitionNames[i]);
      if (BasePage.class.isAssignableFrom(page.getClass())) {
        LOG.debug("Initialising PageFactory elements for page: {}", page.getClass());
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), page);
      }
    }
  }
```

**Sequence of initialising chrome driver**

1. Setup driver via WebDriverManager
2. Set Chrome options for insecure certs and disable quic protocol.
3. Initialise Chrome driver with those options.
4. Open website
5. Add element listeners.
6. Initialise pagefactor elements

**What problem are we facing?**
When we run tests via this project, the browser instance responds really really slow.

1. It takes too long to open Chrome browser after driver instantiation.
2. On submitting the URL via `driver.navigate().to(configuration.getBaseUrl());`, the website takes too long to finish loading. I can see that it takes longer to finish any API requests and resources

**What happens if I run a test from a very simple Java maven project with no setup like above and just the webdriver dependency**
Chrome driver and the chrome browser instance are super fast.

What could be going wrong in the way we are running the tests? Could the problem be because of:

1. Using Spring DI for a lot of classes in the project OR
2. Using PageFactory OR
3. Using Webelement listeners OR
4. Setting those chrome options as mentioned above.

Has anyone come across similar problems? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post all the Classes and methods from where you are initializing and launching the WebDriverManager to launching ChromeDriver() with the framework directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

There might be many possible reasons.
I recommend you to create a sample project on github that everyone could clone and reproduce the problem. Otherwise it's rather impossible to say something helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of slowness got resolved after I tried updating the selenium java binding dependency from 3.141.59 to 4.1.1.

Although I am not sure why/how updating the client side library would make a difference in speed of the browser the driver manages.